# send photo from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to send with ajax a photo from javascript to php.
I have this input in html:

```
<input type="file" class="input-field" id="photo" name="photo">
```

this in javascript:

```
var photo = document.getElementById("photo").value;
```

and this in php:

```
$photo_location = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
```

I am using ajax post to send the photo and some other data in php. All other data are received correctly in php except the photo.  is the getelementbyid .value method which gets the photo wrong ? i get an error undefined index photo from php.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "ajaxpost.php");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var payload = "name=" + name + "&price=" + price + "&quantity=" + quantity + "&description=" + description + "&photo=" + photo;
    payload = payload.replace("%20", "+");
    payload = payload.replace("%3D", "=");

    xmlhttp.send( payload );

    return false;
```

Comment: show us your form and ajax code

Comment: i have added the ajax code

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php

Comment: i dont want to use jquery. what i sthis line doing? `var file_data = $('#sortpicture').prop('files')[0];   `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error is that you send file as normal input so php will recieve it in $_POST not $_FILES.

you can do it using FormData like this:

```
var photo = document.getElementById("photo");

var data=new FormData();
//from inputs
data.append(photo.name,photo.files[0]);
data.append('name',name);
data.append('price',price);
data.append('quantity',quantity);
data.append('description',description);

var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest()
xmlhttp.open("POST", "ajaxpost.php");
xmlhttp.send(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$photo_location = $_FILES['file']['photo'];
```

Comment: try printing the variable:   print_r($_FILES); and see what you get?

Comment: try adding this into your form tag:  enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: sorry for not posting my form but i have it.

Comment: i tried printing the photo i get from this `var photo = document.getElementById("photo").value;` and i get this path `C:\fakepath\images.jpg`

Comment: Can you please post your php code so that I can see how you are getting other values correctly (i.e. name, price, quantity and etc)

Comment: `$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$photo_location = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];`

Comment: what happens if you use $photo = $_POST['photo'];, and echo $photo  ....  in your php file?

Comment: By seeing your ajax code all I can say that use this way. Thats what you want, right?

Comment: I am not sure, i need what is required for me to be able to upload the image with a query to a database. can i do it with the path i get now?

Comment: I you want to save the url of the image in database, then it works.